# Passing the width property of CSS to a CSS variable

Tags: css

I am creating a rounded button that needs to have an oval shape. To put it simply, the `border-radius` property must automatically adjust based on the `width` property that was specified by the user.

```
.tm-round-button {
    display: inline-flex;
    cursor: pointer;

    align-items: center;
    padding: 0px 15px;

    min-height: 25px;
    min-width: 60px;

    border-radius: 30px;
}
```

As you can see, there is a minimal `width` defined for the rounded button. But what if the user or developer decides to use the class and set a more specific `width`? The border will not adjust. I'm not sure if there is a way to achieve this using the CSS variables.

If not, what is the best thing for me to do? Do I use Web Components or JavaScript to do the kind of behavior I want from the button?

Comment: For archive an oval use `borer-radius: 50%`

Comment: This doesn't provide a good look on the button. As it elongates it and causes some text to be obscured.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using percent as a value so it adjust well?

```
    border-radius: 10%;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius

Comment: It doesn't look good. I have already tried this, but the best value of the <code>border-radius</code> is half the current width. Anything less than that makes it look more like a rectangle, not an oval. And anything more than that, makes it obscure the text.